# add custom editview.tpl for sugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I change some things in the `editview` of sugarCRM but I can't find the `editview.tpl` in custom module accounts.

How I can integrate my new file in the `editviewdefs`?

Answer (score 0):

For SugarCRM 6.*, if you use Studio to change your edit view for the Accounts module and do a "Save & Deploy" it will place the changes in /custom/modules/Accounts/metadata/editviewdefs.php.

To do even more customization you can edit this file directly as well as create and edit /custom/modules/Accounts/views/view.edit.php. With the combination of both you can pretty much do any sort of customization that you would need for the edit view.

Comment: i need to add fieldset and something like that where i can add it? when i add this in the editview.tpl it works..there is no folder in /custom/modules/Accounts/views/view.edit.php

Comment: Use Studio to add fields to the edit view whenever possible. You can also edit /custom/modules/Accounts/metadata/editviewdefs.php to add to the layout manually. The view.edit.php will not exist in the /custom directory. You would create it yourself mimicking how it is done elsewhere in the code. Plenty of examples online if you need to go that route, but this isn't for adding fields. More for advanced edit view functionality that you may require.

Comment: yes i know that i can add fields from the studio...but we can't add things like fieldsets or something like that..the only file who contains the html code of the user interface of the account is editview.tpl i want to no how i can for example add the code html in the edit.view.php

Comment: You won't be editing any html code in Sugar to do what you need. You would insert it via your own Smarty template into a field using the customCode attribute for a field in the editviewdefs.php. I guess your question isn't specific enough to get a better answer. The answer is that there is a way to do what you need, but you have to look at it a different way.

Comment: please can you give me your skype